# How to define the width and the height of table in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to define the width and the height of table in html? and how to change the color and font size of that link(covered font with green), 
I would like to let pages beautiful, project_list.html as below, thank you so much for you help:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  </nav>
  <h3 class="mb-3">我学习的课程列表</h3>
  <div class="card">
    <table class="table mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>课程序号</th>
          <th>课程名称</th>
          <th>部门名称</th>
          <th>课程日期</th>
          <th>课程时间</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for course in courses %}
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ course.pk }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle" style="word-break: break-all;"><a href="{% url 'employees:course_detail' course.pk%}">{{ course.name }}</a></td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ course.department.get_html_badge }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ course.date }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ course.time }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% empty %}
          <tr>
            <td class="bg-light text-center font-italic" colspan="4">目前没有你所选技能的课程。</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<div class="card-footer">
```

Comment: `.table .mb-0 { height: 400px; width: 50%;}`. Use [`Boostrap Grid System`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to help with size issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the width, I think the easiest option would be to define specific widths to the thead elements, something like

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="7%">课程序号</th>
        <th width="47%">课程名称</th>
        <th width="20%">部门名称</th>
        <th width="10%">课程日期</th>
        <th width="10%">课程时间</th>
        <th width="6%"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

You can vary the width depending on the resulting table. Percentage widths are always tricky to adjust.

As for the height, it will adjust accordingly. I wouldn't recommend you to assign heights to rows as it would not adjust correctly if the content varies in length.

As for the link color I think the easiest would be something like:

```
<td class="align-middle" style="word-break: break-all;"><a href="{% url 'employees:course_detail' course.pk%}" style="color:blue;font-size:16px;">{{ course.name }}</a></td>
```

In case you use `rem` or `em` you could substitute the `16px` with the value you require.

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt answer, it works, thank you ❤️

Answer (score 0):

Use percents, not pixels for example `<td height="10%">Text</td>   <td width="70%">Text</td>`. Percent will be depended on the surrounding element, you have to adjust it by your needs.

Answer (score 0):

to change the width and height of table you can use colgroup in html. To chnage the colour just specify it in the style element.

```
<table>
<colgroup>
<col style="width:80px" />
<col style="width:80px" />
<col style="width:80px" />
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

To define width for a table you can use `<table width="400">` this will change the table width in detail description given below.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_width.asp

And to change color of your link you can use something like this :

```
<body a link="black" vlink="red">
```

this might work for you : )

Comment: Isn't is body `alink` and not `a link`? Also is it good idea to give width in numbers rather than in percentages?